# Not able to run Thunderbird 3.3a2

Tags: thunderbird

I wanted to try Thunderbird 3.3a2 so I downloaded it from the  [Thunderbird Website](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/early_releases/downloads/). I extracted it and tried to run both files. However I am getting file can not be executed error.

```
amey@amey-desktop:~/Documents/thunderbird$ ./thunderbird
exec: 398: ./thunderbird-bin: not found
amey@amey-desktop:~/Documents/thunderbird$ ls -lart thunderbird*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amey amey 48220 2010-01-01 13:30 thunderbird-bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amey amey  3920 2010-01-01 13:30 thunderbird
amey@amey-desktop:~/Documents/thunderbird$ ls -lart run-mozilla.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amey amey 10597 2010-01-01 13:30 run-mozilla.sh
```

What am I missing? I did also try giving full permission(777) to all three files, still no luck. Tried using sudo too.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this, perhaps your download was corrupted? Have you tried redownloading?

Comment: Let me again try re downloading this.

Comment: Download two more times, still same problem. Can you tell me whether if there is any problem with bash or something.

Comment: I checked the same in my virtualbox guest. It worked fine. Seems that there is some problem with my ubuntu setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are now packages in the Thunderbird Next PPA for 3.3 alpha 2: https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/thunderbird-next

This PPA will also contain future alpha and beta releases of Thunderbird 3.3